# .measure function doesn't work on android (React Native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I use react native. On iOS the function works fine and returns values. On android it returns undefined for all parameters.

```
activeCategoryRef.current?.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px) => {
  console.log(width)
  console.log(px);
  scrollTo(px - width);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It must be added:

```
collapsable={false}
```

to the component that is measured.